# css not affecting link in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am trying to change the color of a link. It is defaulted to blue and I want to override it. I did the following:

```
#site-links a:link{color:red;}
```

and in Chrome's Inspect Element that was the style which overrode all other styles. However, the link remained blue. In Firefox, however, the link is now red.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

`:link` targets specifically a link you have not visited. I'm going to go ahead and assume that in chrome you have visited it. You can fix it by targeting each case as you need it:

```
a:link    { color: red; }      /* unvisited link  */
a:visited { color: blue; }     /* visited link    */
a:hover   { color: green; }    /* mouse over link */
a:active  { color: yellow; }   /* selected link   */
```

Comment: and maintain this order only. because those pseudo classes have priorities. if you do not follow the order you might face rules not working issues.

Comment: I did what you said, and it always remains the color of :visited, even when I refresh the browser... it doesn't even change on hover!

Comment: Have you forced a refresh to overwrite your cache? (cntrl + f5)

Comment: Yes, I just reset the cache and nothing happened.

Comment: @user1015214 hover and active should still overwrite it because they are defined after visited. That order is very important. Have you kept them in that order?

Comment: I've copied them as they are here.

Comment: @user1015214 Then you might have code elsewhere over writing them. It should work. Is the site live? Can you put a version on http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

One way to give higher priority to your rule is stating important in it.

```
a:link { color: red ! important }
```

Also, when in Chrome inspector , to better control what is happening, you can force the state of the inspected element

When in the element inspector, go to the top of the "styles" bar in the right pane. There is an option that states:

"toggle element state"

There you can check / uncheck the :visited status